# What is this algorithm used for?

Tags: python, algorithm

I came across this Algorithm and was wondering what exactly it is, how it's called and what to use it on...

The code (`Python`) is this:

```
def unknown(n):
    n = abs(n)
    a = 0
    t = 2
    while t <= n:
        if n % t == 0:
            a += 1
            n /= t
        else:
            t += 1
    return a
```

here some results:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 2
5 -> 1
6 -> 2
7 -> 1
8 -> 3
9 -> 2
10 -> 2
11 -> 1
12 -> 3
13 -> 1
14 -> 2
15 -> 2
16 -> 4
17 -> 1
18 -> 3
19 -> 1
20 -> 3
30 -> 3
101 -> 1
```

Comment: I think the purpose of that algorithm is to be your homework

Comment: Actually they don't teach CS at my school.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [so] is not homework writing service

Comment: What specific problem are you having understanding the code? We'd be happy to explain some specific part you're struggling to understand, but explaining what some random function does isn't really on topic here.

Comment: Sorry for being rude, just wanted to state what the others are saying, this is not a place to ask questions like that, and don't take the downvoting as people hating on you, thye are trying to teach you how to ask questions.
You can provide what you have tried, what issues do you have etc, pasting an algorithm and saying what does it do might get you an answer, but also a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It brute-force counts the number of prime factors of `n`, each counted according to its multiplicity.

`t` is the current factor being tested and `n % t == 0` only if `n` is an integer multiple of `t`. If it's divisible, `n` is divided and the division is tried again (to account for the multiplicity of that factor); otherwise, the next integer is tried, up to (the original) `n`. Even if the division by non-primes is tried, it doesn't skew the result because all the lower primes have already been tried, so they won't ever succeed.

An obvious optimization would be to compute and memoize the primes up to the number through an efficient algorithm, and just try them.

Comment: Be careful with wording. It is not a _number_ of prime factors, but the sum of powers of prime factors.

Answer (score 3):

It's computing the number of prime factors of `n`. Notice that any prime returns 1.

Comment: I noticed that, yes, but I didn't make the connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the sequence

[Number of prime powers (not including 1) that divide n](http://oeis.org/A001222)

Answer (score 0):

The prime factors of a number n is being calculated

for example
1= 1×1 =0 since 1 is neither prime nor composite

2 = 2×1 => 1

3 = 1×3 => 1

4 = 2×2 => 2

5 = 1×5 => 1

6 = 1×2×3 => 2

7 = 1×7 => 1

8= 2×2×2 => 3